# Trigger CircleCI Build from pull request

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to write a job in CircleCi such that I build the base branch in a pull request using the source code in the feature branch. For example, I add some new assets and tests in feature_1 branch. Feature_1 has an open pull request into "develop" branch. I want to build the develop branch against the source code in "feature_1".

Any ideas?

Comment: Still not following? Are you trying to say that you'd want to build the PR as if it was merged?

Comment: I think you are confused. It sounds to me like you just want to build the feature branch. CircleCI will trigger a build using the source code in the pull request, which should be your feature branch. You shouldn't need to do anything special in order to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess where my confusion stems from is that i want to use deploy the source code from the target branch onto the source. I'm coming from a salesforce background - and salesforce deployments are not very straightforward. The issue being that in order to deploy that code, I need to use the credentials for the target Salesforce server, which I need to derive based on the target in PR.